# The equation $2x^2-2(2a+1)x+a^2+a=0$ has one root less than $a$ and other root greater than $a$,if

Tags: quadratics

The equation $2x^2-2(2a+1)x+a^2+a=0$ has one root less than $a$ and other root greater than $a$,if 
$(A)0<a<1\hspace{1 cm}(B)-1<a<0\hspace{1 cm}(C)a>0\hspace{1 cm}(D)a<-1$

---

As one root is less than $a$ and other root greater than $a$,so $f(a)<0$
$$2a^2-2(2a+1)a+a^2+a<0\implies a>0 or a<-1$$
But the book says answer is $(A),(C),(D)$,i dont know how $(A)$ is possible as answer.

Comment: first thought is C partially implies A if a is upper bound at 1.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I think a better way to explain the relationship between the two is saying that (A) implies (C).

Comment: but it doesn't,  C implies A . A can only be true if C is true. C can be true regardless of if A is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is right and from your solution follows that $B$ is impossible because for $A$
$$(0,1)\subset (-\infty,-1)\cup(0,\infty),$$ for $C$
$$(0,+\infty)\subset (-\infty,-1)\cup(0,\infty),$$ for $D$
$$(-\infty,-1)\subset (-\infty,-1)\cup(0,\infty),$$
but for $B$
$$(-1,0)\cap\left((-\infty,-1)\cup(0,\infty)\right)=\oslash$$

Answer (score 1):

$(A)$ is a sub-case of $(C)$: $0 < a < 1 \Rightarrow a > 0$.

You've proved that $a>0 \Rightarrow f(a)<0$ and hence $a$ lies between the roots.

Combine these two together and you get $0 < a < 1 \Rightarrow f(a)<0$. So $(A)$ is a valid answer too.

Answer (score 1):

If $0<a<1$ we have that

$$f(0)=a^2+a>0$$ and $$f(a)=-a^2-a<0.$$ Thus there exists a root $r\in (0,a).$ Now, from $f(a)<0$ and $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=+\infty$$ we get that there exists a root $s\in (a,\infty).$

Answer (score 1):

If you factor $a$ out, you have the *necessary and sufficient* condition:
$$f(a)=a\bigl(2a-2(2a+1)+a+1\bigr)=-a(a+1)<0$$
hence $a(a+1)>0$, i.e. $\;a<-1\;$ or  $\; a>0$.

A), C) and D) are *sufficient* conditions for this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  Use the [*Quadratic Formula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) to express the roots in terms of $a$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: There is a simple criterion for a number to separate the roots of a quadratic equation.

Comment: @Bernard, what is that criterion?  I am interested to know.

Comment: If $f(x)=c_2x^2+c_1x+c_0$ a separates the roots if and only if $c_2f(a)<0$ (i.e. the leading coefficient and $f(a)$ have opposite signs).